# Element of order 2 in group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

$G$ is a finite group with an irreducible representation $\rho\colon G \longrightarrow GL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Apparently, $G$ must have an element $g$ of order $2$, where either $\det \rho(g)\neq1$ or $\rho(g)$ is central in $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$.

How can I prove this? I've read through my notes several times, but can't see any way to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all such an element of order 2 always exists. This is because of Frobenius' Dimension theorem which states that if we have irreducible representation of a finite group then $d$ divides |G|, where $d$ is the degree of the representation. In your case, the Group $G$ has a irreducible representation of degree 2 and hence $2$ divides $|G|$. Now, Cauchy's theorem gives you the existence.

Now about the other question. What are the central elements of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$? The scalar matrices. Now Let $g$ be an element of order 2. Since $\rho$ is a homomorphism we have $\rho(g)^{2}=e$. Call $\rho(g)=A$. Then we have $A^{2}=id$ . What can we conclude? Either A is  identity itself or $A=-id$ in which cases A is a central element. If not, the minimal polynomial for A is $x^{2}-1$. So, the eigen values are $1$ and $-1$ whence $det(A)=-1 \neq 1$. We are done.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\det\rho(g)=1$. Then $\rho(g)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb C$ such that $ad-bc=1$. But, since $\operatorname{ord}(g)=2$, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$; in other words, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, since $ad-bc=1$. But $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{smallmatrix}\right)\Longleftrightarrow\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{smallmatrix}\right)=a\operatorname{Id}_2$. Therefore, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is central in $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, how do we know that such a $g$ exists?

Comment: @Number34 When I read your question, I missed the “must have” part. I don't know, but I'll think about it.